# Issue with mouse coordinates using HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Fairly new to JavaScript/HTML5 Canvas. Having trouble making a specific area of my background clickable so that it opens up another page. What I want to do is make a selected area of my background clickable, rather then the entire background.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>                  
<html lang="en-US">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Adventures of Balthazar</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function init(){   
   var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   var img = new Image();
   var mouseX = 0;
   var mouseY = 0;
   var btnPlay = new Button(250,555,162,284);

   document.addEventListener('click',mouseClicked,false);

   img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
   }

   img.src='img/menu.png'

   function Button(xL,xR,yT,yB){
    this.xLeft = xL;
    this.xRight = xR;
    this.yTop = yT;
    this.yBottom = yB;
   }

   Button.prototype.checkClicked = function(){
    if(this.xLeft <= mouseX &&
        mouseX <= this.xRight &&
        this.yTop <= mouseY &&
        mouseY <= this.yBottom) 
     return true;
   }

   function playGame(){
    window.location.href = 'index.html'
   }

   function mouseClicked(e){
    mousex = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    mousey = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;

    if(btnPlay.checkClicked()) playGame();
   }
  }
  </script>     
 </head> 

 <body onLoad="init()">
  <div id="canvas-container">
   <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600"> </canvas>
  </div>    
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to help entirely, but I do notice that you declared the variable "btnPlay" as a new button, even though that constructor had not yet been defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working version of your code:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/3PFXa/1/
```

There were two things that I tweaked. (1) you declared var mouseX but you set a "mousex"; (2) use x, y, width and height instead of using left, right, top and bottom coordinates to define your clickable area. This fits nicer with the canvas layout.

Here's the updated code:

```
function init() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    var mouseX = 0;
    var mouseY = 0;
    var btnPlay = new Button(280, 145, 20, 20);

    document.addEventListener('click', mouseClicked, false);

    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        ctx.fillStyle = "#0f0";
        ctx.rect(btnPlay.x, btnPlay.y, btnPlay.w, btnPlay.h);
        ctx.fill();

    }

    img.src = 'http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2013/04/Puppy_2.jpg'

    function Button(x, y, w, h) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
    }

    Button.prototype.checkClicked = function () {

        if ( mouseX > this.x && mouseX < this.x + this.w && mouseY > this.y && mouseY < this.y + this.h) 
            return true;

    }

    function playGame() {
        alert("hello!");
    }

    function mouseClicked(e) {

        mouseX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        mouseY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;

        if (btnPlay.checkClicked()) playGame();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is one small problem I have just realised. When you click on anything below the area you want to be clicked, the function playGame is still triggered which for your example is the alert box.

Comment: Fixed. I made a silly little mistake with "this.h < this.y + this.h" which should have been "mouseY < this.y + this.h", in the checkClicked function.